# Ask for help a inequality problem, does $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-2}\log_2\left(\frac{n-i}{k-i-1}\right)>c\cdot n$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, functional-inequalities, approximate-integration

Can anyone help me to give me a detailed proof (or disproof) of the following
$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-2}\log_2\left(\frac{n-i}{k-i-1}\right)>c\cdot n$ for some constant $c>0$, where $k=\Big[\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\Big]$ and $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$, for example, $x=9.033$, then $[x]=9$.

Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, assuming $n\geq k$

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\log_2\left(\frac{n-i}{k-i-1}\right) &= \log_2\left(\prod_{i=0}^{k-2}\frac{n-i}{k-i-1}\right) \\
&= \log_2\left(\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-(k-1))!}\right) \\
&= \log_2 {n \choose k-1
}
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here? A hint would be to use some inequalities concerning $\log_2 (n!)$ and $n$.

I would suggest looking at [http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/CLASS/HANDOUTS/factorialasymp.pdf](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elaci/CLASS/HANDOUTS/factorialasymp.pdf) and adapting the inequalities to $\log_2$ instead of $\log_e = \ln$.

---

**Alternative Aprroach I (Current method needs tighter lower bound)**

Recall that for $1\leq m \leq n$
$$
\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^m \leq {n \choose m} \leq \left(\frac{en}{m}\right)^m.
$$
Therefore, by monotonicity of $\log_2$ and using $m=k-1$
$$
\begin{align}
\log_2{n \choose k-1} \geq (k-1)\log_2\left(\frac{n}{k-1}\right).
\end{align}
$$
Now, recall the definition of $k$, i.e. that $k = \left[\frac{n}{2\log_2(n)}\right]$, then
$$
\frac{n}{2\log_2(n)} - 1 \leq k \leq \frac{n}{2\log_2(n)} + 1,
$$
thus
$$
\log_2\left(\frac{n}{k-1}\right) \geq \log_2(2\log_2(n))
$$
which gives
$$
\begin{align}
\log_2{n \choose k-1} &\geq (k-1)\log_2(2\log_2(n)) \\
&\geq \left(\frac{n}{2\log_2(n)} - 2\right)\log_2(2\log_2(n)),
\end{align}
$$
which is positive for large enough $n$. Then apply various inequalities regarding logarithms to obtain your answer.

---

**Alternative Approach II**

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\log_2\left(\frac{n-i}{k-i-1}\right) &= \sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\log_2(n-i) - \sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\log_2(k-i-1)
\end{align}
$$
Then, using the fact that
$$
\log(a) - \log(b) = \int_{b}^{a}\frac{1}{t} dt,
$$
we have that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\log_2\left(\frac{n-i}{k-i-1}\right) = \frac{1}{\log(2)}\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\log\left(\frac{n-i}{k-i-1}\right)&= \sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\int_{k-i-1}^{n-i}\frac{1}{t}dt.
\end{align}
$$
Then, letting $ u = t + i$, we have that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\log(2)}\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\log\left(\frac{n-i}{k-i-1}\right) &= \int_{k-1}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\frac{1}{u-i}dt \\
&\geq (k-1)\int_{k-1}^{n}\frac{1}{u-k+2} du \\
&= (k-1) \log\left(n-k+2\right)\\
&\geq \frac{(k-1)(n-(k-1)}{n+1-(k-1)} 
\end{align}
$$
Which is again is not tight enough. A similar approach but with different, but tighter bounds, is advised.

Comment: The total preconditon is that $n=2^r$ where $r=1,2,3,....$. and $k=\Big[\frac{2^{r-1}}{r}\Big]=\Big[\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\Big]$

Comment: @SeekForHelp Apologies for the typo, but the same idea still holds true

Comment: thanks very much. But the estimate is still too corsar. I would like to ask you for help that can we compute it by $\int$? Because $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-2}\log_2\left(\frac{n-i}{k-1-i}\right)=\int_{n-k+2}^n\log_2 t dt-\int_{1}^{k-1}\log_2 tdt$. And the last is $\frac{1}{\log_e 2}\left[n\log_en-(n-k+2)\log_e(n-k+2)-(k-1)\log_e(k-1)\right]$, but it is hard to prove that $\frac{n}{(n-k+2)(k-1)}>e$.

Comment: Thanks! But from $\frac{1}{\log(2)}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-2}\int_{k-i-1}^{n-i}\frac{1}{t}dt$ to $\int_{k-1}^n\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-2}\frac{1}{u-i}dt$, what basis you get that, just letting $u=t+i$?

Comment: @SeekForHelp Precisely, I make that change of variable.

Comment: Thanks and I will adopt your solution. But Alternative II, the last step from $(k-1)\log(n-k+2)$ to $\frac{(k-1)(n-(k-1))}{n+1-(k-1)}$ is incorrect.  And, the $(k-1)\log(n-k+2)$ is enought to me